# Combine multiple ggplots into one plot and save it in Python

Tags: python, ggplot2

I have 7 plots finished with my code. However I do not know how to combine them together into one plot and save it as a PNG file.

In R I used grid.arrange() function but I don't see equivalent pacakges in Python.

Due to consistency reason, I want to avoid using ploting packages except for ggplot2. So it will be great if I can just combine and save them instead of plotting with other new packages.

Thank you

```
p1 = ggplot.ggplot(dt, ggplot.aes(x = "prob",
                                  colour = "target"))+\
ggplot.geom_density(alpha=1,size=3) +\
ggplot.xlab("Pr(target == 1)") +\
ggplot.scale_x_continuous(limits=[min(dt.prob),max(dt.prob)])

p2 = ggplot.ggplot(dt, ggplot.aes(x = "prob",
                                  colour = "target",
                                  fill= "target")) +\
ggplot.geom_histogram(position="identity", binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5) +\
ggplot.scale_x_continuous(limits=[min(dt.prob),max(dt.prob)]) +\
ggplot.xlab("Pr(target == 1)")

p3 = ggplot.ggplot(dt_aggregated, 
               ggplot.aes(x = "coverage", 
                          y = "ppv", 
                          colour = "group", 
                          shape = "group")) +\
ggplot.geom_line(size=5) +\
ggplot.ylab("positive predictive value")

model = sm.GLM(outcome, prob, family=sm.families.Binomial())
smooth = model.fit().predict()
dt["smooth"] = list(smooth)

p4 = ggplot.ggplot(dt, ggplot.aes(x ="prob")) +\
  ggplot.geom_point(ggplot.aes(y = "outcome"),position="jitter",alpha = 0.01) +\
  ggplot.geom_line(ggplot.aes(y = "smooth"), color = "darkblue", size = 1) +\
  ggplot.ggtitle("") +\
  ggplot.xlab("Pr(target == 1)") +\
  ggplot.ylab("target") +\
  ggplot.scale_x_continuous(limits=[min(dt.prob),max(dt.prob)])

p5 = wv_ROCPlot(dt,prob,outcome,returnScores=False)

p6 = gainsPlot(best_model=best_model,validation=False,hex_test=hex_test)

p7 = ggplot.ggplot(dt, ggplot.aes(x = "prob", colour = "target", fill = "target")) +\
    ggplot.geom_density(alpha = 1,position = "fill") +\
    ggplot.geom_line(size=2) +\
    ggplot.xlab("Pr(target == 1)") +\
    ggplot.scale_x_continuous(limits=[min(prob),max(prob)]) +\
    ggplot.ylab("proportional density")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiplot function.
For example, 
multiplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, cols=3)

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I am looking for python function to do the same thing. multiplot() seems like an R function.